# wxPython - wx.MessageDialog disappears without click

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm new to wxPython (wxPython 3.0.0.0, python 2.7, Mac OS X), and I'm trying to display a message dialog in the OnInit function of the app.  Example scripts I run work just fine using a very similar three-line code block, but when I do it with this one, the message dialog appears for a split second, and disappears.  Is there something silly that I'm doing wrong?

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):

  def __init__(self):
    wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)

  def OnInit(self):
    self.rootView = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title="Wire Frame",
      pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 250))
    self.rootView.Show()
    self.SetTopWindow(self.rootView)
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self.rootView, "Hi", "title", wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = MyApp()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Edit: Tested this on Ubuntu with wxPython 2.8.12.1, and the behavior is normal there.  I'll try and get a newer version on there to test it with.  Perhaps this is a bug in wxPython?  I've submitted a bug report, so I'll find out soon enough.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this behavior.  This code seems to work on my system.

Comment: It seems to work on other systems as well - Perhaps it's platform-specific.  I edited the question with other testing I've done.

Comment: It works fine on Windows 8, wxPython v3.0 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will happen if you treat MessageDialog as if it is say FileDialog or similar?

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.App):

  def __init__(self):
    wx.App.__init__(self, redirect=False)

  def OnInit(self):
    self.rootView = wx.Frame(parent=None, id=-1, title="Wire Frame",
      pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 250))
    self.rootView.Show()
    self.SetTopWindow(self.rootView)
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self.rootView, "Hi", "title", wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    #dlg.ShowModal()
    if dlg.ShowModal() != wx.ID_OK:
        dlg.Destroy()
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = MyApp()
  app.MainLoop()
```

probably just a hackish way to go around but this may work...

At least, this seems to work in the same way in wxpyhon2.8 on Windows.

Comment: My apologies for not getting back to this.

This did work as a hack around the issue, so you have my thanks!   

I also submitted a bug report to the wxwidgets guys, and they have fixed this with the new release of the toolkit.